# Only show registers from a current_user Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show only the registers (patients) from a user (medic) that creates the register

In my controller I have:

```
  def index
    # @patients = Patient.all
    @medic = Medic.find(params[:id])
    @patients = @medic.patients
  end
```

I get error: Couldn't find Medic with 'id'=

In my view I have:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <%= patient.name %>
<% end %>
```

In my models I have:

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medic
end
```

¿How can I do this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `params[:id]` by default in your `index` method; it is a collection route not a member route. So always the value of `params[:id]` is `nil`

If you would like to index patients of a certain `medic` you can go to `localhost:3000/patients?medic_id=x` and in your controller use

```
if params[:medic_id]
  @patients = Patient.where(medic_id: params[:medic_id]).all
else
  @patients = Patient.all
end
```

If you use `devise` and you have a `current_medic` defined then just get patients for the current medic using

```
@patients = current_medic.patients
```

`localhost:3000/patients` will now display patients or logged in user.

You have to add a `before_action :authenticate_medic!` to your controller.

Comment: I try as you suggest, but when I logout and login whit another user (I'm using omniauth-google-oauth2) show exactly the same records with user that creates the records

Comment: then how manage medic, with patients, consultations, and prescriptions?, and I cant put  before_action :authenticate_medic!, it rederect's me to a log_in path in devise but I'm logged with omniauth...